# Making an element visible and hide upon click

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an element `#mask123` visible or hidden upon click. By default, the element is hidden, but as I click it becomes visible. The js below works on first click, and the element turns visible. Now, I would like to click on the same button `#menu-btn-toggle` and the element toggles into invisible mode, which I cannot make it work. I am using inline css here. This is a simple case but my limited knowledge on js is not helping me.

```
   <div id="menu-btn">
      <a href="#" title="Menu" id="menu-btn-toggle" class="menu-icon-link" onclick="showMask();">
    </div>
```

the html code

```
<div class="side-nav--mask">
    <div class="js-side-nav-mask liquid-container">
        <div id="mask123" class="liquid-child" style="visibility: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMask() {
        var node = document.getElementById('mask123')
        node.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
</script>
```

When I try to a condition (below) it does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMask() {
        var node = document.getElementById('mask123')
        node.style.visibility = 'visible';
        if node.is(":visible") {
            node.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to toggle the `visibility` property based on current value of it,

```
function showMask() {
    var node = document.getElementById('mask123')
    var visibility = node.style.visibility;
    node.style.visibility = visibility == "visible" ? 'hidden' : "visible"
}
```

You are accessing the jquery's `is()` function over a plain node object. Node object doesn't have function called is in its prototype.

Answer (score 4):

```
function showMask() {
    var node = document.getElementById('mask123');
    if (node.style.visibility=='visible') {
        node.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else
        node.style.visibility = 'visible'
}
```

This is how you should use your if condition :)

Comment: @ Urvashi, thank you for your time. I have upvoted you.

Answer (score 2):

`.is` is a jquery method. To use it, you first need to wrap your element/selector with jquery - `$('#mask123').is(':visible')`.

But you don't actually need jquery for this, you can do it in basic JS:

```
function showMask() {
    var node = document.getElementById('mask123')
    if (node.style.visibility === 'visible') {
        node.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        node.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using jQuery you can use a simple function and a CSS class:

```js
// after removing onclick="" attribute from html 

$('#menu-btn-toggle').click(function(){
  $('#mask123').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
#mark123.visible{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Note that in this case you also have to specify that `#mask123` is initially hidden in order to do the transition to visible.

So you have to add this to your CSS

```
#mask123 {
  visibility:hidden; /* initial state = hidden */
}
```

-

[**Working jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v23f787L/)

Comment: @dbf He/She included the jQuery tag in the question, so he/she probably don't

Comment: Still you ask if he minds, would have been a more complete answer for both with and without jQuery. jQuery tag will be removed from the OQ anyhow I guess ..

Comment: @dbf yes sure, a solution with both would have been even better. I used jQuery just to provide an alternative solution, imo more compact and clear, as a good pure javascript solution was already posted by another user and I didn't wanna steal it. Simple as that :)

Comment: Ok, then get used to "stealing" if that is what you call it, it's not stealing, there are only a few ways of writing code, there are no copyrights you have to be concerned about, and if someone else posted the equivalent solution then at his name to it for credit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use ClassList.toggle and since you are using inline code you will need important

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("#menu-btn-toggle"),
    mask123 = document.querySelector("#mask123");
function classToggle() {
      mask123.classList.toggle("visible")  
    }
btn.addEventListener("click", classToggle, false)
```

```css
#mask123.visible{
    visibility: visible!important;
  }
```

```html
<div id="menu-btn">
      <a href="#" title="Menu" id="menu-btn-toggle" class="menu-icon-link">Click to toggle </a>
    </div>

<div class="side-nav--mask">
    <div class="js-side-nav-mask liquid-container">
        <div id="mask123" class="liquid-child" style="visibility: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1;">Some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```